# Функция отображения цвета для даты

Tags: дата, php

Вроде бы ничего сложного, просто мозг кипит уже(

Есть 3 даты.  Для каждой нужно выбрать определенный цвет:

- Красный, если она еще не наступила.
- Оранжевый если она еще не наступила, НО и не наступила предыдущая (т.е она следующей идет).
- Зеленый, если уже прошла.

Т.е. нужна функция, которая на входе получит 3 даты. или 2. Т.е. я не могу придумать правильную архитектуру функции. Возвращать она должна только цвет. И вызываться она будет 3 раза. Не за 1 раз выдает цвета, а 3 раза. Дат может быть 2.

Для чего это нужно? Для Х этапов задано время. Например, первый - 12.04.2012, второй - 13.04.2012, третий - 14.04.2012

Сейчас - 07.04.2012. Значит, сейчас идет первый этап. Он кончится 12.04 и тогда начнется второй этап.

Вот нужно наглядно отобразить.

Comment: Даты произвольные, либо упорядочены?

Comment: Упорядочены.
При добавлении в базу проверяется, чтобы вторая дата не была раньше первой. т.е второй этап не может начаться раньше первого. и т.д

Comment: Мне кажется, в вашей ситуации будет проще, выполнять проверку на все необходимые условия в функции, а возвращаться массив с цветами. Либо если есть прям такая необходимость пользоваться глобальными переменными, либо классом.

Comment: Я знаю... но как мне передавать в нее данные?
например:

get_color(date1,date2,date3); // для первой даты
get_color(date1,date2,date3); // для второй даты

т.к даты идут не подряд, а в разных таблицах
т.е вызовы этих ф-й разделяет по 50-300 строк кода.
а может всего 1 вызов

Comment: Т.е. функция должна быть универсальная. Или просто при вызове передавать такие данные: для первой даты  `get_color(time(),date1,date2)`, для третей `get_color(date2,date3,time())`.

Answer (score 1):

Есть некоторый сумбур в вопросе , сложно сообразить. Но я представляю так
Есть нека БД  'project' в которой точно есть поля
id- ключь этапа в базе
number - реальный номер этапа
name - наименование этапа
date - дата начала этапа

Пишем следующий запрос к базе

```
SELECT project . * , t.number, t.number - project.number
FROM `project` , (

SELECT number
FROM `project` 
WHERE date <= CURDATE( ) 
ORDER BY number DESC 
LIMIT 1 
) AS t
WHERE ABS( t.number - project.number ) <5 //число 5 - сколько этапов покажем до и после текущего
ORDER BY project.number
```

ТАк вот в результатет запроса по полю t.number - project.number можно определить какой это этап:

если > 0 зеленое - уже прошел

если =0 - текущий

если =-1 - то следующий - красный

если >=-2 то оранжевый

Comment: Нет.Немного не так....  В базе просто 3 поля даты.  Этапа всегда 3 максимум. Это определено законодательством в данной сфере.

Там кот нужна некая ф-я которая получит 4 аргумента вот так: get_color($date1,$date2,$date3,$etap)
Дата 3 может быть пустой, тогда этапа 2.
И вот ф-я смотри если нам нужен цвет этапа 2 ($etap=2) тогда он сверяет дату2 с текущим временем, предыдущей.  Если этап=1, то с текущим временем и возвращает цвет. Так наверно и сделаю...   Всего 3 условия в функции получится